# Setting ImageView src from an image in Windows's drive

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an image in my D drive (D:\...\Image.jpg) and I want to display it in my app, the thing is Im getting the image name from the database, and in my code Im doind something like:

```
image_view.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("D:\\Program Files\\Image_Folder\\"+item.Img_Name));
```

But Im getting an error saying there is no such file as (D:\Program Files...\Image.jpg), basically it's a No File Found Exception but Im sure the path is correct.

So I can't add it to drawable folder because I don't know wich image the user will select, and it would be silly to put all the images in the drawable folder to avoid this problem.

Any Ideas ?! Thank you.

Comment: put your image file to drawable folder

Comment: As per your current logic, how do you plan to access the image once it is deployed on various devices? There won't be any *D drive* on the device. And from where will the user select the images?

Comment: I see thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access images on another device like that. You need to either put all the images you need in the drawable folder, or set up a webserver on which you can get the images over a network connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get image only from device file directory, assets or drawable folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access from your local drive it is supposed to be somewhere in your package or alternatively if only local directory is the option you can setup an ftp server through **FileZilla (Server)** and access your local drive through sharing.

Thanks